# Very fast replication

Tags: postgresql, replication

I have used [the Streaming Replication guide](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Streaming_Replication) on the PostgreSQL Wiki to configure replication between my two db servers.

But, when I updated a row on master server it is available on the slave **instantly**. It should be asynchronous, isn't it? What I am missing?

Servers are in separate places. The master's upload speed is ~75kb/sec. As far as I know, first of all, 16MB xlog file should be upload to slave, after that transactions available on slave. But it is happening in 1 sec. Why is it so fast?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Async* and *Slow* are not the same thing. If you start putting real load on the replication stream, you will start to see delays, but not with a single test command.

From the PostgreSQL Wiki entry you linked to:

> In SR, XLOG records in partially-filled XLOG file are shipped too, implementing record-based log-shipping.'

So streaming replication is exactly that: The stream of updates is transported from master to slave.